# Knockoutjs & FancyForms: visible-binding not working on selectboxes using transformSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding, fancyform

so I discovered the following problem using knockoutjs (v 3.2.0) and fancyforms (v 1.4.2) together in a webapplication:

I've got two `select` boxes(referred to as "dropdown" further on) and two links on a html-page.

Now the desired behaviour is the following (just a short pseudocode, see below for jsfiddle-scenarios):

```
if(dropdown1.value == "a1"){
    dropdown2.value = "b3";
    dropdown2.hide()
    chosenlinkbutton = chosenlinkbutton1;
    chosenlinkbutton2.hide(); //realized via knockoutjs-visiblebinding and a param
} else {
    //show and reset stuff...
}
```

The Problem is: my second dropdown does not get hidden. Instead, there appears another dropdown. As I investigated this problem , I found out it is because fancyform transforms the actual selectbox into ul/li-list structure. But to be honest I have no clue on how to (re-)apply my binding to the generated code of fancyform or to re-instantiate fancyform after changing the value, so I hope you could help me out here.

JSFiddle showing the problem. Just change "weekView" to "monthView" to see that the other dropdown does not disappear:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnmav1e8/8/

And a working JSFiddle with commented-out fancyform:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnmav1e8/7/

In this version, I actually just commented out the line

```
$("select").transformSelect();
```

But sadly I need the app to work with fancyform, so I hope some of you could help me out here!

Best regards,
Dominik

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eawa16g2/

Comment: wuah.... reading your code: 10s. Realizing knockoutjs has commentbased bindings: 30 minutes! Thank you very much, exactly what I need! Just create an answer out of this if you want (a few lines of explanation would be nice!). If you woin'T, i'll do tomorrow :)

Comment: Also note: if you wanted to use `visible` (which doesn't work in virtual tags) instead of `if`, you could wrap the element in a `div`. http://jsfiddle.net/fnmav1e8/13/

Comment: Hey, sorry for not explaining my comment, I was in a hurry and just wanted to provide you with a working example. Also Roy gave you a better answer (better practice) using a visible binding on a container. This way you don't have to reinstantiate fancy forms every time subscribe get triggered (with IF binding you have to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI toolkits like Bootstrap and Fancy Forms often rewrite the DOM to introduce stylized versions of the standard widgets. The trick to controlling their visibility in Knockout is to put the Knockout bindings on a container around the widgets.

```
    <div data-bind="visible:isWeekView">
        <select id="selectCals" data-bind="value: mode">
            <option value="default">Default</option>
            <option value="defaultplus">Standard plus</option>
            <option value="none">nothing</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Alternatively, you can use an [`if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), which has the advantage of working in [virtual tags](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).

Comment: ok, so you got the answer :) thanks for the explanation and the visible-part, though!